# Dividing a number into infinite pieces

Tags: divisibility, infinity

Last day in physics teacher said that any number divided into infinitely many pieces is zero.It got me thinking in kind of weird direction so here is what I was thinking about and how I tried to disprove that number divided into infinite pieces is 0.

For example take number any irrational number and let it be between 1 and 2.Lets call that number $x$ and let $y=x-1$

Now we can have an injection from set of natural numbers(not including 0) into interval [0,y],now let F be injection such that natural number n is mapped to the real number such that it lies in the given interval,its n-th decimal is equal to n-th decimal of y,and all decimals before it are 0.

For example if y=0.431232426577... then F(3)=0.001

Now we have practically divided the irrational number x into infinitely many pieces since,the infinite sum  y+$\sum_{i} F(i)$ approaches x for any partial sum.

Thus we have proven that number divided into infintely many pieces is necesarrily zero.How true is this,am I on a right path?
Does it even make sense to talk about dividing into infinitely many pieces?

Comment: Is this a proof or a disproof of what your physics teacher claimed?

Comment: It is not clear what you are saying. What do you exactly mean by "a number divided into infinitely many pieces is zero"?

Comment: @Vanio: It is true that if you try to subdivide a length on the real line into infinitely many pieces, and you demand they are all of the same size, you will find that "all of the pieces have length 0" (in some rigorous sense). Of course, if you do not care that they are all the same size, then all bets are off, as you showed.

Comment: I mean as Eric Stucky explained

Comment: I would think that the teacher was expressing that for any number $x$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x}{n}=0$.  Whether this was expressed in the most precise way possible is questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Any number divided by an infinite number of equal parts is zero**

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{n}{x}= n\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} =0,\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{R} $$
As mentioned by paw88789, in the comments. Also note that in this case, it is more mathematically precise to use the word **by** as opposed to the more ambiguous word **into**.